# Update two table or more Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to update 2 tables frm_data_aset and frm_monitor at the same form. in frm_data_aset have column lokasi_aset and in frm_monitor have column lokasi_monitor, I want Both columns insert same value.

When I try to run this I enter code here I'm getting an error :

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: Data_aset::$M_monitor
>
> Filename: controllers/Data_aset.php
>
> Line Number: 120

how to update 2 tables in codeigniter?

**My function on controller**

```
{
    $this->_rules();

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->create();
    } else {
        $data = array(
    'pengguna_aset' => $this->input->post('pengguna_aset',TRUE),
    'tglkirim_aset' => tanggal_db ($this->input->post('tglkirim_aset',TRUE)),
    'lokasi_aset' => $this->input->post('lokasi_aset',TRUE),
    'komputer_aset' => $this->input->post('komputer_aset',TRUE),
    'monitor_aset' => $this->input->post('monitor_aset',TRUE),
    'keyboard_aset' => $this->input->post('keyboard_aset',TRUE),
    'mouse_aset' => $this->input->post('mouse_aset',TRUE),
    'printer_aset' => $this->input->post('printer_aset',TRUE),
    'scanner_aset' => $this->input->post('scanner_aset',TRUE),
    'stabilizer_aset' => $this->input->post('stabilizer_aset',TRUE),
    'ups_aset' => $this->input->post('ups_aset',TRUE),
    'finger_aset' => $this->input->post('finger_aset',TRUE),
    'switch_aset' => $this->input->post('switch_aset',TRUE),
    'ket_aset' => $this->input->post('ket_aset',TRUE),
    'user_modify_aset' => $this->session->userdata('user_id',TRUE),
    'date_modify_aset' => $this->input->post('date_modify_aset',TRUE),

    );
        $data2 = array(
    'lokasi_aset' => $this->input->post('lokasi_monitor', TRUE),
    );

        $this->M_data_aset->insert($data);
        $this->M_monitor->insert('frm_monitor;$data2');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Create Record Success');
        redirect(site_url('data_aset'));
    }
}
```

But if I am just updating single table, it is working, without this code

```
 $data2 = array(
    'lokasi_aset' => $this->input->post('lokasi_monitor', TRUE),
    );
$this->M_monitor->insert('frm_monitor;$data2');
```

Comment: You probably have not loaded the model `M_monitor`. YOu need `$this->load->model('M_monitor');` before you try using it.

Comment: I trying to use this code 
'$this->db->where('kd_monitor;$kd_monitor');
$this->db->insert('frm_monitor', $data2);'

but i get error this

**Error Number: 1048
Column 'lokasi_monitor' cannot be null
INSERT INTO `frm_monitor` (`lokasi_monitor`) VALUES (NULL)**

Comment: Share your `M_monitor->insert` function in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->M_monitor->insert('frm_monitor;$data2');
```

should be:

```
$this->M_monitor->insert('frm_monitor', $data2);
```

assuming your `insert` function does something like:

```
function insert($form, $data) { ...  }
```

Also your field cannot be NULL as per your database schema thus:

```
$data2 = array(
    'lokasi_aset' => !is_null($this->input->post('lokasi_monitor', TRUE)) ? $this->input->post('lokasi_monitor', TRUE) : ''
);
```

Comment: Now I got this error :
**Error Number: 1048
Column 'lokasi_monitor' cannot be null
INSERT INTO `frm_monitor` (`lokasi_monitor`) VALUES (NULL)**

Comment: print_r($data2) before insert and report the array

Comment: only showing this  **Array ( [lokasi_monitor] => )**  and error above.

Comment: well there is you error... there is no data, and the field cannot be  NULL which it is. Either make it so the field can be null in your database or do: `        $data2 = array(
            'lokasi_aset' => !is_null($this->input->post('lokasi_monitor', TRUE)) ? $this->input->post('lokasi_monitor', TRUE) : ''
        );`

Comment: now I can insert into $data2, but there make new row, I want to insert into row monitor which I select on the form

Comment: The table does not allow null values in the 'lokasi_monitor' column and a NULL value was set for the new row.